# No Bean Named Available - XML Configuration

Tags: java, spring

I have been trying to create simple Spring application and I am unable to run it due to the following the "No Bean Name Available" error.

[Source folder and files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmfkp.png)

My main class code is as follows:

```
package org.example;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:example.xml");

        Container obj = (Container) context.getBean("container");
        obj.stores();

    }
}
```

My XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">
    <bean id="container" class="org.example.Box"/>
</beans>
```

And for this, I get the following error;

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=9650:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Pradeepani\IdeaProjects\SampleSpring\target\classes;C:\Users\Pradeepani\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.16.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Pradeepani\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.16.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Pradeepani\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.16.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Pradeepani\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.16.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Pradeepani\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.16.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Pradeepani\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.16.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar org.example.App
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'container' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:779)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1106)
    at org.example.App.main(App.java:11)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have gone through many solutions, but they all seem to work for the annotation configuration and not the XML configuration.

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Remove `classpath*:` and just load `example.xml` (the `classpath` is the default for the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`) and I suspect you will get a `FileNotFoundException` or the likes when doing so. Then fix the path or put the `example.xml` in the right place.

Comment: @M. Deinum What do you mean "fix the path or put the `example.xml` in the right place" ? Have I specified `example.xml` in the wrong place? It is in the same source package as the rest of the classes.

Comment: it should be in the root and if you are maven should be in `src/main/resources` and not in `src/main/java`. Also there is a difference between `classpath:` and `classpath*:` (and as `classpath:` is the default stick with that) the latter is pattern and if it doesn't detect anything will happily continue, the other will throw an exception if it cannot load the file!.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added an image of the source folders. Please let me know if it is correct. Thank you.

Comment: See my previous comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this.

I needed to create a directory within the main folder named "resources".

By shifting the XML configuration file into that folder, I was able to execute the program.

Comment: Which is what I explained exactly in the comment from the 8th of July.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your advice. I added the answer only today.

Comment: I'd like to stress that 'classpath*:' should be removed. I had the exact same setup as the OP, so not only should you create src/main/resources, but 'classpath*:' needs to be removed for this to work.

Comment: I have "resources", it's marked as the resources root, I don't have the word "classpath", the annotations are in place, the xml file contains `<context:component-scan base-package="[package name]" />`, as it should, but container still doesn't have the bean 